# How can I use a replacement rule as part of a simplification?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, expression-manipulation

I am using Mathematica to symbolically calculate the likelihood for a simple linear regression model. As part of this I want to substitute

```
{(1/n)*Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] -> OverBar[x], (1/n)*Sum[Subscript[y,i],{i,1,n}]->OverBar[y]}
```

that is, replace these sums with the means. However, my estimate (after using `FullSimplify`) is
$$\left\{\frac{\sum _{i=1}^n y_i-\beta _1 \sum _{i=1}^n x_i}{n},\frac{\left(\sum _{i=1}^n x_i\right) \sum _{i=1}^n y_i-n \sum _{i=1}^n x_i
   y_i}{\left(\sum _{i=1}^n x_i\right){}^2-n \sum _{i=1}^n x_i^2},\frac{\beta _1^2 \left(n \sum _{i=1}^n x_i^2-\left(\sum _{i=1}^n
   x_i\right){}^2\right)+2 \beta _1 \left(\left(\sum _{i=1}^n x_i\right) \sum _{i=1}^n y_i-n \sum _{i=1}^n x_i y_i\right)-\left(\sum _{i=1}^n
   y_i\right){}^2+n \sum _{i=1}^n y_i^2}{n^2}\right\}$$

so when I do the substitution, nothing is replaced because these terms do not explicitly appear by themselves in the equation (at least I assume this is why a simple replacement rule does not work).

For example say I have the quantity above and I call it "MLE" in mathematica, and the replacement rule above is called "rule". If I do

```
MLE /. rule
```

nothing is changed. Is there I way I can coerce mathematica into finding these terms and substituting them in this way?

Comment: The trick is to use a simpler expression as the first argument of `Rule`.  Try this:   `rule = {Sum[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}] -> n * OverBar[x], 
  Sum[Subscript[y, i], {i, 1, n}] -> n * OverBar[y]} ;  MLE /. rule // Simplify`

Comment: @LouisB awesome, thanks! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.This works great. I'm going to work on getting the estimate in terms of Sxx/Sxy as well, is there any explanation for why my rule doesn't work, but this version does even though they are equivalent?

Comment: In my understanding, when a replacement rule does not work it is because the pattern (first argument of `rule`) is not matched *exactly* in the target (`MLE`).  Use `FullForm[ MLE ]` to expose the expression(s) that must be matched by the pattern.  Use `FullForm[ rule[[1]] ]` to see the exact pattern being used by `ReplaceAll`.  Thanks for the offer to accept.  Hopefully someone else will come up with a more deserving answer / explanation.